# Does Blender 2.8 still have skeleton sketching?

Tags: rigging

Watching an older tutorial where it's possible to make bones by checking "skeleton sketching". I can't find it in Blender 2.8

Comment: Edit your question, to better understand what you are looking for and place the tutorial link you mentioned, since I haven't found what you are mentioning

Comment: [Tutorial Blender in Limba Romana: #70 Skeleton Sketching](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xWvQIlUM7EU)

Answer (score 1):

Blender 2.8 doesn't have this feature anymore. The reason is that the feature was rather obscure, not used by many people and the implementation had several bugs. You can see the discussion in [ticket T52809](https://developer.blender.org/T52809) in the official bug tracker. The commit [rB36773e35f6009693562330137435271922758b95](https://developer.blender.org/rB36773e35f6009693562330137435271922758b95) removed this feature back in April 2018 from the master branch.